# Restricting Nested Scroll View to stop scrolling when the content is not needed to be scrolled

Tags: android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I am implementing an activity with article view like this [image: like this]

What I am trying to do is ... if the content is not necessary to be scrollable , I want to limit the scrolling behaviour of Collapsing Tool bar ( Image View ) & NestedScrollView with its child relative layout(Green one).
Collapsing Tool bar layout has been stopped scrolling successfully when there's no content to scroll .
But when the nestedScrollView is scrolled even if the content is too small to be scrolled and that nestedScrollView is causing to scroll the appbarLayout.

So how can I stop scrolling the nestedScrollView if there is no content to be scrolled as in this picture?

This is what I have Tried.

```
private void adjustContentSize(double contentHeight) {
    int totalScreenHeight = getScreenHeight(this, 1);
    showLog("initial Content height -> " + contentHeight / totalScreenHeight);
    if (contentHeight > (totalScreenHeight * 0.35) && contentHeight < (totalScreenHeight * 0.45)) {
        double contentHeightPercentage = round(contentHeight / totalScreenHeight, 4) + 0.0001;
        double appBarHeightPercentage = 1 - contentHeightPercentage;
        binding.newsContentView.setMinimumHeight((int) (totalScreenHeight * contentHeightPercentage));
        binding.newsHeadIv.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (totalScreenHeight * appBarHeightPercentage);
        unlockAppBarOpen(binding.articleAppBarLayout, 1);
        showLog("-----------------Content Height : " + contentHeightPercentage + " , Appbar Height : " + appBarHeightPercentage);
        changeAppbarLayoutDraggableBehavior(binding.articleAppBarLayout, false);


    } else {
        showLog("---------------------------------UnAdjustable content------------------------------------");
    }

}    

  private void measureContentSize() {
    double contentHeight = binding.newsContentView.getMeasuredHeight();
    double totalScreenSize = getScreenHeight(this, 1);
    double contentPercentage = contentHeight / totalScreenSize;
    if (contentPercentage < 0.35) {
        binding.newsContentView.getLayoutParams().height = getScreenHeight(this, 0.35);
        changeAppbarLayoutDraggableBehavior(binding.articleAppBarLayout, false);
    } else if (contentPercentage == 0.35) {
        changeAppbarLayoutDraggableBehavior(binding.articleAppBarLayout, false);
    } else {
        adjustContentSize(contentHeight);
    }
}
```

I have called `measureContentSize()` method after I have set the data to the layout.